# <ui:param/> name must match el value on WebSphere but not Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jsf, primefaces, websphere, el

This works perfectly on Tomcat:

```
<ui:include src="myPage.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="myForm" value="#{theForm}" />
</ui:include>
```

but when I  deploy it onto WebSphere, I get this error:

```
Error Caught: 
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'myForm' resolved to null
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:101)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:249)
```

To get it to work on WebSphere, I need to change the name to be the same as the el expression inside the value:

```
<ui:include src="myPage.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="theForm" value="#{theForm}" />
</ui:include>
```

I'm sure that I shouldn't have to do this. Is it a bug in WebSphere? Is it documented anywhere? Is there some way that I can choose the name to be whatever I want?

Comment: My guess here is that there is some other underlying issue that's causing this difference.  Which JSF implementation are you using, and did you change versions after moving to WebSphere?  Are you getting any other JSF exceptions in your application logs?

Comment: @wtlucy It's version 2.2 and we use the same version in tomcat (for development) as we do in websphere (for testing). This is the only error in the logs.

Comment: Can you post the relevant backing bean source?  Also, what WAS version are you on?

Comment: The backing bean is nothing special. I've encountered the problem before with different beans, but this time I decided to ask a SO question. I'll find out the WAS version on Monday, and post another reply then.

Comment: @wtlucy websphere version 8.5.5.4

Comment: "version 2.2" is just JSF spec version. What's more important is the actual implementation (Mojarra or MyFaces) and its version. WebSphere ships with MyFaces and generally a rather ancient version. Problem at least suggests that your classpath is littered with multiple different versioned JSF libraries. Most likely you're bundling an incompatible JSF implementation along with the webapp (which would be required for Tomcat) while WebSphere has its own already. At least, the way how you formulated the question strongly suggests that this is the case.

Comment: Okay, this is making a bit more sense now. I hadn't properly understood wtlucy's question about implementations. @BalusC is correct - we bundle the jsf-api and jsf-impl jars with the web-app. They come form Mojarra, so I guess they are conflicting with WebSphere's MyFaces. Should we exclude the Mojarra jars when deploying to WebSphere, or tell WebSphere not to use MyFaces?

Comment: Right - WebSphere 8.5.5.4 provides MyFaces 2 at runtime, by default.  If you decide to use the MyFaces implementation that's provided, then you should definitely remove the jsf-* jars from your app.  If you want to use another JSF implementation, then you need to configure that implementation to live in an isolated shared library.  There are instructions for doing that here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html

Comment: Thanks @wtlucy. If you put all that into an answer below, then I'll accept it. The comments from Balus C were helpful too, but he has plenty of rep already.

Comment: glad we've figured this out, @whistling_marmot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments on the original post, this type of problem occur when multiple JSF implementations are present on the application's classpath.  In the case of traditional WebSphere, the JSF 2.0 MyFaces implementation is provided, by default, to all applications.  In this case, a third-party JSF implementation should not be bundled directly with the application without additional configuration, as that can cause these kinds of classpath conflicts.

In traditional WebSphere, either the provided JSF implementation should be used, or the desired JSF implementation should be configured in an isolated shared library and associated with the app.  Instructions for using third-party JSF implementations can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html).

As a note, in WebSphere Liberty, the JSF implementation that's provided by the server can be enabled/disabled by the user.  So, for this case, bundling a JSF implementation with the app would be fine as long as a `jsf-2.*` feature is not enabled.